# Does system image Windows 10 backup all my saved browser passwords and profiles?

Tags: google-chrome, backup, browser, system-restore, windows-system-image

I have been told that using the full system image backup will create a full copy of every file on my boot partition. However, I have also heard that when copying saved passwords in some browsers, it would require a "sync" or some other in-browser feature for them to successfully be backed up as otherwise some sort of encryption interferes with this process (this may be my incorrect understanding, though). I manage a lot (50+) of different browser profiles within different browsers and so I am wondering if I create a full system image backup of my C drive it will encounter any problems with the saved passwords or any other browser data e.g. logged-in accounts logging out or if I will be able to continue as normal with no hiccups. Thanks!

Comment: Chrome and Firefox can encrypt passwords that are saved.  If that is the case depends on your individual profile. In both cases they are encrypted by the user.  If you are worried about your saved passwords you will want to take complete system images (i.e. third-party software) instead of using the very limited built-in tools.  You might look at other solutions then using a browser as your password manager, something that can be shared between multiple browsers, and not having to worry about user specific encryption.

Comment: Hi, @Ramhound, is it okay to ask which third party software you would recommend for making such a complete system image instead of using the Windows in-built one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A true full-disk image will save your whole disk, including everything
that the browser knows or remembers. The data of the browsers is saved
along with every folder and file and even the boot software and data.
Everything.

The Windows Backup program is not recommended - use a third-party product.
My favorite is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html),
but there are others.

Comment: Other alternatives are free Macrium Reflect (https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) or others: https://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/ . BTW, a full disk image might be *faster* than the selective Windows Backup, since it can use dirct disk I/O, though storing more data.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: AOMEI (at least) doesn't backup unused sectors and compresses the data. The image is much smaller than the disk.

Comment: Reflect gives options for compression (how much, or none), for forensic copy (all sectors, byte-for-byte) vs. used sectors, etc., as likely do most commercial and free imaging tools. One can take the defaults (used sectors only + moderate compression), or go for a smaller yet image using higher, but slower, compression, or *verbatim* image.

Comment: @DrMoishePippikso macrium reflect will give me an exact 1:1 copy of the drive and it will be as if nothing happened / changed at all after transferring? Thanks!

Comment: @William: That's the same with several backup products - AOMEI & Reflect are comparable products, and there are others.

Comment: @harrymc The free version of macrium reflect will be able to do this? Also (final question) is it quite self-explanatory or is there some YouTube tutorial you would recommend when doing an exact 1:1 byte system backup?

Comment: AOMEI & Reflect are both free and able to backup the entire disk, with the ability to create an emergency boot USB to restore the disk. I find AOMEI to be simpler to use and so avoid making mistakes, but that's my personal preference.

Comment: Sure! Thanks everyone.